# How to route traffic by proximity from Route 53 to closest NGINX server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I'm trying to set up a web server stack in the following way:

- Use Route 53 for my DNS
- Serve static content with Cloudflare from S3 buckets
- Route API calls to nearest NGINX server that sits in front of some Nodejs     servers.

So all static content is done easily enough but how can I route my api traffic to the nearest NGINX server depending on location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want geolocation routing for the api endpoints:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-geo

Comment: Any idea how I'd go about routing my api traffic from route 53 to nginx? So for example www.example.com/examplePost?

Comment: you basically do this by creating the records in the route53 zone for example.com. see http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/aws/route-53-geodns-tutorial/

Comment: also look at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/route-53-domain-reg-geo-route-price-drop/ you see the AWS Route53 console. the magic happens where locations and different targets are specified

Comment: I see how you can do subdomains but how about routes as I described: www.example.com/examplePost?

Comment: @JoshElias DNS doesn't work at the "route" (path) level, although if cloudflare supports path-based routing, your geo-routed subdomain (pointing to dispersed nginx machines) could be a hostname *behind* cloudflare, with the geo-routing based on the nearest one to the cloudflare edge a particular browser hits.